# How to no separate into Output and Input when using AUTOINST with verilog-mode

Tags: emacs, verilog

For InstModule like this

```
        module InstModule (
           input i1,
           output [31:0] o1,
           input i2,
           output [31:0] o2);
        endmodule
```

verilog-mode will expand it

```
           InstModule instName
             (/*AUTOINST*/);
```

into this

```
           InstModule instName
             (/*AUTOINST*/
          // Outputs
          .o1           (o1[31:0]),
          .o2           (o2[31:0]),
          // Inputs
          .i1           (i1),
          .i2           (i2));
```

However, I hope it can be like this.
Just like declaration order and not separate into two groups.

```
           InstModule instName
             (/*AUTOINST*/
          .i1           (i1),
          .o1           (o1[31:0]),
          .i2           (i2),
          .o2           (o2[31:0]));
```

Is there a setting of verilog-mode I can rely on?

or is there a way I can modify verilog-mode.el to achieve this?

I searched https://veripool.org/verilog-mode/help/ and verilog-auto-inst-sort isn't what I need.

It changes the order in Outputs and Inputs list, but still separate into two groups.

Did some further research and find out it might be something with interface from system-verilog.

```
    module_a U_A(/*AUTOINST*/);
        
    interface_io U_IF(clk);
```

```
    interface interface_io;
        modport A(
            input i1 ,
            output [31:0] o1
        );  
        modport B(
            input i2 ,
            output [31:0] o2
        );  
    endinterface
```

However, it results in this, similar to implementation in 2010
https://github.com/veripool/verilog-mode/issues/270

```
    module_a U_A(/*AUTOINST*/
         // Interfaces
         .U_IFA         (U_IFA.A),
         .U_IFB         (U_IFB.B));
```

I was expecting something like this, which is what I want.

```
    module_a U_A(/*AUTOINST*/
         // U_IFA Interface
          .i1           (i1),
          .o1           (o1[31:0]),
         // UIFB Interface
          .i2           (i2),
          .o2           (o2[31:0]));
```

Comment: No.
The code in that problem description is exactly what I want.
The answer provided there won't help as I am using a much newer version of verilog-mode.
If possible, I want to ask @Omnivore directly. How does he/she get the code? by verilog-mode or it is actually hand written?

Comment: For reference.The problem is this one.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65238707/how-to-get-declaration-order-autoinst-with-emacs-verilog-mode

Comment: Older versions of verilog-mode.el can be obtained by downloading older versions of emacs. Overwrite the same file in the new install tree with the old .el file, then M-x byte-compile the rolled back version now on the drive. Emacs will look for the byte-compiled version first. Maybe it provides the functionality you are looking for. –

Comment: If you don't get the answer you are looking for then try posting  at https://emacs.stackexchange.com/  The emacs gurus are there.

Comment: I tried that version(2017-08-07-c085e50). not work.
I add some information that may help. about interface and modport.

Answer (score 2):

**TL:DR** Someone is already trying to add this feature, just wait.

Someone already created an issue asking the exact same question.

https://github.com/veripool/verilog-mode/issues/1745

The contributor's answer as followed.

> No, because the // Input and // Output comments are "magic" so they need to be in that order. Sorry.

According to this answer, the best result I can expect would be like this.

```
    module_a U_A(/*AUTOINST*/
         // U_IFA Interface
           // Inputs
          .i1           (i1),
           // Outputs
          .o1           (o1[31:0]),
         // UIFB Interface
           // Inputs
          .i2           (i2),
           // Outputs
          .o2           (o2[31:0]));
```

Another people also created a similar issue, saying he/she would give it a try to add this feature.
I'll count on him/her.

https://github.com/veripool/verilog-mode/issues/1816

Answer (score 0):

Grouping the ports by **Input**/**Ouput**/**Inout** is required by verilog-mode for other features, such as AUTOWIRE, and is stated as such in the FAQ/documentation.

https://github.com/veripool/verilog-mode/blob/master/FAQ.rst#why-doesn-t-autowire-include-the-outputs-from-a-submodule

More importantly, why do you want the tool (verilog-mode) to provide you with **less** information? I see no functional benefit to your desired output.